# Charles Web Proxy reads but doesn't write session on Mac OS

Tags: macos, proxy, charles-proxy

I installed Charles Web Proxy 4.1.1 on my Macbook OS Sierra with encryption.

I'm unable to get Charles to write any of the requests into the session panel. At the bottom left, I can see it's reading traffic but nothing appears in either the Structure or Sequence panels.

I deleted the application and reinstalled it granting it permissions to auto-configure itself. This didn't seem to resolve the issue either.

I installed the SSL certifications as described and this had no effect either. I'm now about 3.5hrs into trying to figure out how to get program up and running.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 steps together fixed my issue:

1. In '[username] > Library > Preferences, look for files that include  "charles", there were 2. Delete them.
2. In '[username] > Library > Application Support, look for a folder named "Charles", delete it

Restart Charles so it re-writes everything from scratch. You should see traffic as soon as the application finishes opening up.

Comment: Somehow, Charles configurations was messed up on my MacBook after an update. I followed your instructions, but beware that you will lost the license if you have one.

Comment: That is an excellent thing to be aware of. Thanks for the tidbit.